# How to populate Drop down list depending on the Selected column of a ASp.Net Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am fairly new I wanted to know how to populate a drop down list on select of a grid view column. I have a grid view and it has a data then i have a Drop down list I want user's to be able to click on the item in the grid view and load its ID in the Drop down list. It will make things easier for them to work with.
Please let me know if you have any idea how to do it.
Thanks.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvdata" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

This is the Gridview.

```
Dataseet ds = new dataset(); gvdata.datasource = ds; gvdata.DataBind();
```

This is how i populate it.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlItemID" Width="100px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
```

This is the Drop down.

```
    DAL DAL= new DAL(Context, "spgetItems");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();dlItemID.DataSource = ds; 
    DlItemID.DataTextField = "ItemID"
    DlItemId.DataValueField = "ItemID"
    DlItemID.DataBind();
```

This is how I bind the Data to it.

Comment: Can you provide sample code of what you have so far?

Comment: Please read it [MCVE]

Comment: There i added all tho i don't have issue with it i just want to know the way to do it not what i have.

Comment: I still don't really understand your question. You click on a GridView column and a DropDownList outside the GridView is (re)populated based on that column?

Comment: Yes you click on a Column and the Dropdown list gets populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quiet easy. I don't know why no one got it but here it is.

```
      <asp:GridView ID="gvdata" EnablePersistedSelection="True"  DataKeyNames="ItemID"
         runat="server"
         HorizontalAlign="Center"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvdata_SelectedIndexChanged"
         CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  > 
             <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
              </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="lable"  BackColor="White" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

and now the c#

```
 protected void gvdata_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lable.Text = "";
    lable.ForeColor = Color.White ;
  lable.Text = gvData.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    dlItemID.ClearSelection();
   dlItemID.Items.FindByValue(Lable.Text).Selected = true;

}
```

I simply put the selected comand value in a lable and then use the findbyValue in the dropdownlist by the value of the lable and select it very simple.oh one more thing the lable forcolor is set to white because than it matches the background color of the lable and it kind of like invisible but still there,rather then any Css property hidden features.